# socket.io 0.9 discover error

Tags: node.js, websocket, socket.io

I'm building a mobile game using flash client and socket.io 0.9 server.
My game got popular and I got like ~300 connected clients at any time.
When the server is working for 24 hours, suddenly it starts responding only in ~10% of the cases.
I debugged the flash client and the socket.io library tries to load as HTTP this url:

http://host.com:123/socket.io/1/?time=14187588...

Normally it receives status code 200 with something like:

`Io70X_FFWJFdyCpfp_3w:40:60:websocket,htmlfile,xhr-polling,jsonp-polling,flashsocket`

but when the server hangs - in 90% of the requests it receives response code `0` and no data, and in the other 10% of the cases receives the correct data and connects successfully.

Any ideas?